# DropShadowEffect direction follows the RotateTransform of a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

I need some help regarding my dropshadoweffect. i am currently working on rotating a control with a dropshadow. but when i'm rotating the control, the dropshadow also follows the direction. these are the sample images:

[this is the normal look of the dropshadow when the user control is not yet rotated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd1vr.png)

[and this is the dropshadow after rotating the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkmrD.png)

this is my code for that control and dropshadow:

```
<local:CogWheel x:Name="CogWheel2" Width="100" Height="100" GearColor="#FF4D5D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="105,13,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <local:CogWheel.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="100"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </local:CogWheel.RenderTransform>
                    <local:CogWheel.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF4D5D" BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="12" Direction="280" Opacity="0.70"/>
                    </local:CogWheel.Effect>
                </local:CogWheel>
```

i want to rotate a control but retain its dropshadow direction. any help would be appreciated. thank you!

**EDIT:**

I solved it by my own by putting the control i am rotating to a transparent grid and adding the dropshadow to the grid instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the Angle to the Shadoweffect direction to retain the effect

```
   var rotate = (CogWheel2.RenderTransform as TransformGroup).Children.Where(x => x is RotateTransform).FirstOrDefault() as RotateTransform;
        this.shadowEffect.Direction = 280 + rotate.Angle;
```

Comment: but do you know how can i get the rotation angle value of the control i am rotating with?

Comment: @MarkSuckSinceBirth edited the answer, I am not sure how you do rotation

Comment: Oh i see. but i also solved my question by my own, i've got the same output by just adding the control i am rotating with to another grid and putting the dropshadow into the grid instead. and the dropshadow will not be affected. still thanks a lot. i upvoted your answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Applying the dropshadow effect on a parent grid do the job.

To elaborate on Justin CI's answer : binding the `DropShadowEffect.Direction` to the `RotateTransform.Angle` also works. It's convenient when animations come into play.

```
<local:CogWheel x:Name="CogWheel2" GearColor="#FF4D5D" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <local:CogWheel.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="100" x:Name="rotation"/>
    </local:CogWheel.RenderTransform>
    <local:CogWheel.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Direction="{Binding Angle, ElementName=rotation}" Color="#FF4D5D" />
    </local:CogWheel.Effect>
</local:CogWheel>
```